# @SpringBootTest does not autowire JavaMailSender and throws error

Tags: spring-boot, jakarta-mail, spring-boot-test

What am I doing wrong here? My understanding is Spring should autowire JavaMailSender the way its autowiring EventRepository. Any guidance?

### application.properties and application-test.properties

```
mail.host='smtp.gmail.com' -
mail.port=587
mail.username=username
mail.password=password
mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

---

## My Implementation class : **This works fine if I run my application**

```
      @Service
            public class EventService {
             private EventRepository eventRepository;
             private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

                public EventService(EventRepository eventRepository, JavaMailSender   javaMailSender) {
                    this.eventRepository = eventRepository;
                    this.javaMailSender = javaMailSender;
                }

                public Event send(Event event) {
                   SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
                    message.setText("");
                    message.setSubject("");
                    message.setTo("");
                    message.setFrom("");
                    javaMailSender.send(message);
                    return eventRepository.save(event);
                }

            }
```

## My Integration Test class : Able to Autowired EventRepository but not JavaMailSender.

```
       @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
        @SpringBootTest
        public class ApplicationIntegrationTests {
            @Autowired
            private EventService eventService;

         @Test
            public void test() throws Exception {
                eventService.save(new Event());
        }

        }
```

## ERROR:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.mail.javamail.**JavaMailSender**' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1486)
```

Answer (score 3):

Please make sure that your test reside in the same `package` as your main `@SpringBootApplication` class.

for example if `@SpringBootApplication` class is in `src/main/java/some/package` then your `@SpringBootTest` need to be in `src/test/java/some/package`. If it is not, you need to explicitly set `@ComponentScan` to include `some.package`. You can also use `@SpringBootTest(classes=...)`, `@ContextConfiguration(classes=...)}`.

You can also put a `@SpringBootConfiguration` class in your test package that scans for your main package.

Comment: Did you managed to resolve this issue? I am having the same problem.

Comment: check : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2876#issuecomment-96624625 and https://www.codesd.com/item/is-it-possible-to-autowire-the-configuration-of-a-spring-project-configuration-to-another-spring-project.html.

Answer (score 2):

In my case that was caused by difference in application.properties files in main and test resources.

Following properties were missing in test file:

```
spring.mail.host=<my host>
spring.mail.port=<my port>
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=3000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000
```

Please note that it is not best idea to use external services in unit tests.

Answer (score 2):

You should define one of the properties `spring.mail.host` or `spring.mail.jndi-name` for spring autoconfiguration or define your own bean in your config class.

Check this class `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mail.MailSenderAutoConfiguration` for details.

Example:

```java
@Service
public class MyEmailService {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

}
```

```java
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mail.MailSenderAutoConfiguration;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
   properties = "spring.mail.host=localhost", // <--- inlined property
   classes = {MyEmailService.class, MailSenderAutoConfiguration.class}
)
public class MyEmailServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyEmailServiceTest emailService;

    @Autowire 
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender; // if you need

    @Test
    public void validEmails() {
        // some tests of emailService
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, this works even without @SpringRunner. the key here is to include the AutoConfiguration classes, in my case I had to add ThymeleafAutoConfiguration as well, as I use Thymeleaf as the template engine.

Answer (score 0):

Autowire Rule:
The are only two, i said `ONLY TWO` possibility for Autowiring to throw null.

1. You manually created Object using `NEW` keyword. In IoC framework environment you should let the framwork do it's shit.

for example `private AnyMailSender mail = new AnyMailSender()`

2. Some Object might been left Non-Autowired. In you case you are not Autowiring this line

`private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;`

You should do something like this

`@Autowire private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;`

Answer (score 0):

Your need to create a bean. Just like below in your configuration package(if you have).

```
@Bean
public JavaMailSender getJavaMailSender() {
    JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    mailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
    mailSender.setPort(587);
    
    mailSender.setUsername("my.gmail@gmail.com");
    mailSender.setPassword("password");
    
    Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    
    return mailSender;
}
```

And put @Configuration annotation above the class

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the SpringBoot class and the Test class have the same package name

Answer (score 0):

Your object should be configured properly.
Use 'JavaMailSenderImpl' instead of that, Declare your @Bean with any of the following ways,

```
@Autowired
private JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender;
```

Or

```
JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
```